# No sound device is detected in Ubuntu 16.04 until I kill pulseaudio

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio

No sound device is detected by my Ubuntu system unless I run

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse
pulseaudio -k
```

Then the sound device is detected. After shutdown or restart the problem returns.

How can I fix this?

Comment: try removing speech-dispatcher : sudo apt remove speech-dispatcher also remove mpd or other sound daemon in case  you installed it.

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`killall pulseaudio` and `pulseaudio -k` (or `pulseaudio --kill`) have same function. i don't see why final command should be needed

When Pulseaudio starts it checks home folder configuration for user settings. If there are none found, a fresh default set of files is created.
Pulseaudio used to use ~/.pulse, recent versions switched to ~/.config/pulse.
Check hidden folders in home with file manager and you should only find one of those folders (probably the second one)

If anything to get your sound working isn't saved to configuration or deleted, default configuration is re-created with same error after restart

- Open Pulseaudio Volume Control (`pavucontrol`)
  don't rely on volume
  control in panel, pavucontrol shows all needed settings
- Check in Playback tab to see if audio playback showing and not muted
- Go to Configuration tab, try setting all devices to OFF first
- Change only one device to "analog stereo playback"
  (digital is ok if can't use analog, stereo and playback only to keep it simple temporarily for troubleshooting)

If sound starts working, reboot PC to check if audio working and configuration saved.